# How to get the newly created object inside the .Select() in a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get a reference to the 'parent' object in the Linq below. Something like the way EF does it when you query for objects that are of EF Classes?

```
void Main()
{
  IEnumerable<SomeModel> Brands = ....;
  var list = Brands
    .Select(b => new BrandModel()
    {
      ID = b.ID,
      BrandName = b.Name,
      Locations = b.Locations.Select(l => new LocationModel()
      {
        ID = l.ID,
        LocationName = l.Name,
        Brand = *here I would want the Brand object of this Location*
      }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
}

private class BrandModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string BrandName { get; set; }
  public List<LocationModel> Locations { get; set; }
}

private class LocationModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string LocationName { get; set; }
  public BrandModel Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @PaulSuart I suppose OP wants the newly created `BrandModel`, not the `Brand`.

Comment: What is `Brands`? Is it collection of `BrandModel`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere you are right.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Brands is a collection of some other class, that's different from BrandModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `BrandModel` in two steps. First create it without locations, then set locations to it

To do so you need to convert your lambda `b => new BrandModel()` to block of statements `b => { return new BrandModel() }`. Try this code:

```
.Select(b =>
  {
      var model = new BrandModel
      {
          ID = b.ID,
          BrandName = b.Name
      };

      model.Locations = b.Locations.Select(l => new LocationModel
      {
          Brand = model
      }).ToList();

      return model;
  });
```